# selinux policy issue for variable created using device_attr

Tags: android, selinux

I have created device_attribute usb_sock in my driver, driver is loaded in boot time. usbd application will write sock fd to device attribute created.

```
static DEVICE_ATTR(usb_sock, S_IWUSR, NULL, store_sockfd);
```

And also for selinux, created object in file_context for sysfs entry,
/sys/devices/platform/dummy_hcd.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/usb_sock       u:object_r:sysfs_mydriver_usb:s0

but it is not taking effect once driver is loaded in boot time and device attribute is created in runtime.

result:

```
xxx:/sys/devices/platform/dummy_hcd.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 # ls -lZ

-r--r--r-- 1 root root u:object_r:sysfs:s0 4096 2017-01-09 18:13 usb_sock

denied:
<5>[   73.393423 / 01-09 13:06:14.540][7] .(7)[4049:usbd]audit: type=1400 audit(1483985174.540:20): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=4049 comm="usbd" name="usb_sock" dev="sysfs" ino=22182 scontext=u:r:usbd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

Android N OS

Comment: Please use 
ps -efZ | grep usb_sock

It'll give more detail about object, and follow the link https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials
I hope you'll find your solution.

Comment: bhanusingh grep for what? ps -efZ this is command not supported in my android device. ok i will check thank you